# find the label which contains the "required text"

Tags: c#, label

In C# Winforms, while user first load the form, I get the input as a label 'text' into database by clicking on that label. After again if another user loads that form, I want to make that label disabled. How can I make that ?? This is the form sample

[image]

This is I'm tried:

- If the user clicks more than one label I get the input string as " E10,E9,E8,E7 etc., "
- when another user loads the form I retrieve that string and split
  that by using "," and stored it in a array

  But I don't know how to make that label disable from the array. Help Please.

Comment: The approach you tried sounds sensible. Why it didn't work?

Comment: Can you tell me how to find the label which contains the "required text"

Comment: Ok, I've edit my answer with a code that Is currently working in my VS2010. Please, confirm it works before the European Final Soccer Match (Spain vs. Italy) starts ;) I will not be here then :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**strong text**1.- Do a loop in your array
2.- Find the label using the name of the label (I've supossed that the name of the label is the same that the imput string you have in the array)
3.- Disable the control

```
foreach (string name in yourArray)
{
   var matches = this.Controls.Find(name , true);
   ((Label) matches).Enable = False
}
```

I don't have a compiler here right now, I hope it runs. Please, be understanding if not.

**Edit**: Find a label by his text property:

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if(c is Label)
   {
      if((Label) c).Text == "RequiredText")
      {
          // Do stuff here ;
      }
   }
}
```

Please, note that if the label is inside a panel, groupbox, or any content control you will have to udo contentControl.Controls instead of using 'this'.

**Edit 2:** Ok, This code works for me. I've a label with text "Sample".

```
    var myarray = "E1,E2,Sample".Split(',');

    foreach (Control labelcontrol in this.Controls)
    {
        if (!(labelcontrol is Label)) continue;
        foreach (var text in myarray)
        {
            if (labelcontrol.Text == text)
                labelcontrol.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it shows error, cannot convert type 'system.windows.form.control[]' to 'system.windows.form.label'. It means???? What should I do? The name of the label is not same as input string:(

Comment: probably needs an index because its returning an array, change it to ((Label)matches[0])

Comment: Thanks for the help. But now the exception was 'Index as outside the bounds of array'. I declaed strarray as "string[] strarray = retr_seats_upper.Split(comma);"

Comment: PLease, edit yout question and put the code. I'll help you to fix it.